# 2 JSONP Requests Called. 1 Works, But Another Returns Parsererror

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

Refer to the link : http://jsfiddle.net/LS8zs/

I tried to get JSON data using **jQuery .ajax()** from api of Kongregate.com

"Get User Badges" works. (plz click to try)

But "**Get All Badges**" doesn't.
Code is basically the same. But error occurs:

```
parsererror : Error: jQuery17209025343011599034_1339162861022 was not called
```

I also tried to add `?callback=foo` to the end of the URL, but no luck.

Would some body help me please?

I'm newbie in programming. I think I miss something about *same origin policy*, right?

Or the api just doesn't support ajax call via javascript/jQuery?

Note that I'm using **Ruby On Rails 3.2** to develop the web app. Should I use ROR to get JSON data instead? *(In the best practice)*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just typing:

http://www.kongregate.com/badges.json?callback=foo

into a browser doesn't return JSONP. But it does for:

http://www.kongregate.com/accounts/andrew/badges.json?callback=foo

So I'm guessing JSONP callbacks aren't supported for the first URL at all.

The Same Origin Policy shouldn't matter if jQuery is handling the JSONP request correctly.

Comment: So, does the solution is getting the JSON data in server side? e.g. rails, php... Thanks!

Comment: Yeah some sort of proxy on your server would be required it seems. So **www.myserver.com/kongregate/badges.json** could return the results of **www.kongregate.com/badges.json** for example.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation!! It's time for me to dig deeper in Ruby on Rails :D